# Extract class name by prefix using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I am a newbie with jQuery and trying to extract class name from element with the specific prefix.

I have achieved this by using javascript as below,

Code:

```js
var classes = $('#elementID').attr('class').split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
  var matches = /^id\-(.+)/.exec(classes[i]);
  if (matches != null) {
    var resID = matches[1];
  }
}

console.log(resID);
```

```html
<div id="elementID" class="id-3212 sort filter"></div>
```

By using the above script i can extract the class name which is start with the prefix '**id-**' and get the result as **3212**. Here i'm trying to extract the whole class name i.e **id-3212** using jquery.

I think this can be done in simple and less code using jQuery. How can i extract the whole class name using jQuery ?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: `/^(id\-.+)/` would include the id in your regex match

Comment: If you have control over the HTML I would suggest you change it. `<div id="elementID" data-foo="3212" class="sort filter"></div>` is much easier to access and read, and avoids having to hack around any identifying strings placed in `class` attributes.

Comment: Use `matches[0]` to get the whole match. There's no need for a capture group if you don't want to extract the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `element.classList` to get an array-like list of all the classes.

Convert the classList to a "real" array then you can use `.filter` with `.startsWith` (or a regex here if need really old browsers that don't have .startsWith (or a polyfill))

```js
var id = [...document.getElementById("elementID").classList].filter((x) => x.startsWith("id-"))[0];

console.log(id)
```

```html
<div id="elementID" class="id-3212 sort filter"></div>
```

To get the classList if you already have a jquery object:

```
$('#elementID').get(0).classList
```

---

As an alternative, you may find it easier to add data via a `data-` attribute rather than a one-off class name (assuming you'll have classes such as `id-1` `id-0099`)

```
<div id="elementID" class="sort filter" data-id="3212"></div>
```

Comment: @Barmar good call, forgot the split(' ') when looking into classList